# Send requests directly to couchDB from NodeJS/Angular application?

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb

I'm currently building a new web-application with user registration, profiles, image upload and so on. I was using the MEAN stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, Angular, NodeJS) for previous projects and now want to try out couchDB.

couchDB delivers a REST-API for free. I could shift all the logic to the client and make sure, that the input is valid by couchDBs validation functions. Therefore I could make the requests from client directly to the database and I would not have to code annoying things like CRUD Operations in my expressJS controllers. Authentication, Validation and simple CRUD operations - it's all there and for free.

Is there a reason not to do so? I would then pass the request to my server and then pass it on to the couchDB from there, which pretty much eradicates all the nice benefits over mongoDB.

greetings,
Michel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your proposal is at least theoretically true and you might want to go ahead and do it, perhaps forwarding requests from the browser to couchdb with a reverse proxy like nginx or node-http-proxy. I believe there are products on the market espousing this "no application server" architecture such as [parse.com](https://parse.com/products/core), which provides some social proof that this idea is at least interesting and worth exploring.

However I think you will at some point discover there is such a thing as an application server and people use them and write code for them in nearly every application for good reason. Debugging problems with your couchdb data validation code is probably going to be cumbersome at best. Compare that to the amazing features you have debugging node.js code with node-inspector and the chrome developer tools debugger.

couchdb is also probably not going to provide realistically granular enough authorization capabilities. This means eventually your application will be exposed to malicious users just doing a PUT with the right document id and gaining access to data they are unauthorized to see or change.

Very few applications are simple enough that UI + DB can handle all of the data transitions and operations that are needed. You could in theory code some of this logic in the browser, but having the Internet between your compound query logic and your database is going to add so much latency to your app to make some features impossible, especially if you have to do a query, get some results, then do a secondary query based on each of those results. That is sometimes feasible between a server-side application and its couchdb, but doing that across the Internet will suffer from the latency.